# Session interconnection in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am developing application in JSF,Hibernate,Spring.

I have a list of projects that are assigned to logged in user,and that list is stored in session level variable.

Now if admin deactivate that project than all the user that are logged in and has that project in list, from list that project should be removed.

So how can i alter the value of one session level variable based on other session level variable in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

Have the object implement HttpSessionBindingListener and keep track of what sessions it is currently bound to. When it is deactivated, it can then unbind itself from all those sessions.